# Android BLE simultaneous Notification and Indication

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So my application uses Bluetooth Low Energy, and requires the use of Notifications and Indications. However, I have not been able to enable the Indications. Is it possible to have Notifications and Indications simultaneously enabled? If yes, is the method bellow valid to do it?

```
    gattInstance.setCharacteristicNotification(charac, true);
    BluetoothGattDescriptor desc =  charac.getDescriptor(UUID_CCCD);
    desc.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    desc.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
    gattInstance.writeDescriptor(desc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `desc.setValue`, you actually overwrite previous value. So here, you write CCCD with `INDICATION` enabled only.

Per Core Spec v4.2, §3.G.3.3.3.3, CCCD is a bitfield, so you should be able to write 16-bit little endian value 0x0003 (there seem to be no constant defined in BluetoothGattDescriptor for this).

Comment: `ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE = {0x01, 0x00}` and `ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE = {0x02, 0x00}`. So maybe if I use `enableNOTIFandIND = {0x03, 0x00}` it might work.

Comment: Yes that might work. But it's also up to the peripheral if it will actually send both the indication and the notification. Why do you want to enable both anyway? Seems like you can solve whatever you want to achieve in some better way. Indications are also quite pointless since if you want the acknowledgement you can't really be sure the app handled it; only that the stack got it (maybe the app wasn't responding or crashed, Android will still send back an acknowledgement).

Comment: @AmiguelS, yes, that's the value.

Comment: @Emil, I agree, I don't see the use case either. I'm quite certain most stack implementations will not handle this correctly, but that's not the actual question...

Comment: @Emil My application requires me to compensate for packet travel time, and I would like to use the same characteristic to send the data and use the ACK of one of those messages to estimate the travel time. The remaining data would be sent using Notifications. It seems that I would be better off creating a dedicated 'ping' characteristic.

Comment: Why don't you just use the connection interval (+ slave latency) to determine travel time? Or are you trying to measuring how responsive the host of the central is?

Comment: Purpose of GATT is to have one characteristic for one usage, and not multiplex again on top of it. Here you seem to do exactly that.  Dedicated ping characteristic seems more obvious to me.